# Image in hoverover in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to put an image in a hoverover of a cell in excel? Either from a link or something else, like another cell or files?

I've had a look at comments, and cell validation. And I haven't seen anything from googling either.

Comment: Are you looking for Mouse Over button,, on Sheet or Hover button on Form or on Sheet ?

Comment: @RajeshS just on a cell in a sheet

Comment: My experience says that any picture can't be hovered but yes a Label can,, !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the steps below:

1.Right-click the target cell and select Add comments.

2.Delete all text in the comment input box.

3.Mouse moves to the edge of the comment input box, and when the pointer becomes a cross arrow, right-click to select "Format Comment"

[image]

4."Colors and Lines" - "Fill Effect" - "Select Pictures"

[image]